# Why value doesn't updated correctly in Vue when using v-for?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I've created basic jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wetdr5nq/1/).

```
var child = Vue.component('my-child', {
    template: 
    '<div> '+
      '<div>message: <input v-model="mytodoText"></div>  <div>todo text: {{todoText}}</div>'+
      '<button @click="remove">remove</button>' +
    '</div>',
    props:['todoText'],
    data: function(){
        return {
        mytodoText: this.todoText
      }
    },
    methods: {
        remove: function(){
        this.$emit('completed', this.mytodoText);
      }
    }
});

var root = Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '<div><my-child v-for="(todo, index) in mytodos" v-bind:index="index" v-bind:todoText="todo" v-on:completed="completed"></my-child></div>',
    props:['todos'],
    data: function(){
        return {
        mytodos: this.todos
      }
    },
    methods: {
        completed: function(todo){
        console.log(todo);
        var index = this.mytodos.indexOf(todo, 0);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.mytodos.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  render: function (h) { return h(root, {
      props: {todos: ['text 1', 'text 2', 'text 3']}
    }); 
  }
});
```

Code is simple: root component receives array of todos (strings), iterates them using child component and pass some values through the `props` 
Click on the top "remove" button and you will see the result - I'm expecting to have

> message: text 2 todo text: text 2

but instead having:

> message: **text 1** todo text: text 2

From my understanding vue should remove the first element and leave the rest. But actually I have some kind of "mix".

Can you please explain why does it happen and how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that Vue try to "reuse" DOM elements in order to minimize DOM mutations. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

You need to assign a unique key to each child component:

`v-bind:key="Math.random()"`

where in real-world the key would be for example an ID extracted from a database.